# How can I update a list in flutter, after adding a new item to the list?

Tags: flutter, dart

Okay guys, need your guidance, just started learning flutter (i am a java developer):

Imagine we have a simple list of ListTile widgets:

List testList = [

```
ListTile(
leading: CircleAvatar(
  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(url
  ),
),
title: Text('Title text'),
subtitle: Text('Subtitle text'),
trailing: smth here also,
```

),
];

Imagine there are 1-2-3-n items in this array.

Now we want to display this list in a listview, seems quite simple:

```
children: <ListTile>[
      for(ListTile e in testList)
          e
    ],
```

Now we have all the elements.
Okay, now I want to add new list tile, and this is where I am stuck:

Let's add a dialog, which I am going to call every time the button is pressed:

```
TextEditingController txtController = TextEditingController();



Future<String> createTxtDialog(BuildContext context) {
return showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
  return SimpleDialog(
    title: Text("Input text"),
    children: [
      TextField(
        controller: txtController,
      ),
      MaterialButton(
        elevation: 5.0,
        child: Text('Submit'),
        onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop(txtController.text.toString());
        },
      )
    ],
  );
});
```

}

Okay, now let's call this function with our button:
// Here I want to add new item to my existing list and instantly get updated list:
// I will create a new list tile with only one row - this is going to be text received from our text controller:

```
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      createTxtDialog(context);
      setState(() {
        testList.add(
          ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(url
              ),
            ),
            title: Text(txtController.text),
          ),
        );
      });
    },),
```

So the problem is:

My list is updated normally, everything is okay, but I cannot see updated list until I reload my application.
I want to have my list updated "on the fly" - as soon as I add new item to the list - my new item is going to be displayed instantly

How can this be solved?
Thank you in advance! :)

P.S.
List updated, but with no text from the dialog

Comment: Are you using stateful or stateless widget?

Comment: I am using a stateful widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **initState** and define your default testList in it.

```
 initState({
  // testList definition
});
```

After you add item to list, you can call **setState**.

Comment: Where should I add initState? And let's imagine that this list will differ from user to user (I will change list to the database), how this is going to help?

Comment: Above of the Widget and it have to in class.